# Click Button Before being Hidden by JS

Tags: jquery

I've a **textarea** that when It's focused I want to show a button near that text.

My process was:

```
<div class="div_textarea col-lg-6">
  <button class="button pull-right invisible" type="button">click</button>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50">Test</textarea>
</div>
```

Put the textarea and button in same DIV:

click
  Test

Use JS to Hide and make the button visible:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".div_textarea").focusin(function() {
    $(this).find('button').css('visibility', 'visible');
  });
  $(".div_textarea").focusout(function() {
    $(this).find('button').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  });
});
```

The problem:

When I click the button, the click event is not happening since the button is hidden first. What can I do to solve this?

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/15dc4kch/1/).

Edit:

I've used this to solve the issue as stated by some users:

```
$(".div_textarea").focusin(function() {
  $(this).find('button').css('visibility', 'visible');
});
$(".div_textarea").focusout(function() {
  $(".div_textarea").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find('button').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  })
});
```

Comment: It did not work the way I expected. The delay to hide has to be at least 100ms or the button event does not fire. Very odd. See below. I am concerned as a magic number should not come into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use mouseenter() and mouseleave() instead of focusin/out?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".div_textarea").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).find('button').css('visibility','visible');
    });

    $(".div_textarea").mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).find('button').css('visibility','hidden');
    });

  $("button").click(function(){
    alert("foo");
  });
});
```

Comment: I've used part of your solution. Thanks mate. Just added to the main topic.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't even use `focusout`, it's complicating things far too much and you really don't seem to need it. It would be better to have the `.button` handle the reverse state. This also will reduce your lines of code.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".div_textarea").focusin(function() {
    $(this).find('button').css('visibility', 'visible');
  });

  $('.div_textarea button').on('click', function() {
    console.log('works')
    $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
  });
});
```

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fm2xtbb6/1/)

Comment: Thanks mate. The issue is that I've this so called "divs" replicated throughout the entire code.